# How to install a plugin (Joda-Time) in grails > 2.3 when built with maven

Tags: maven, grails, jodatime

I am using Grails 2.3.5 and need to install the Joda-Time plugin to make use of the taglibs for formatting dates.

I created a simple grails application using the command: "grails create-app test-app"

I then converted it to use a maven pom by executing: "grails create-pom com.company"

I can then package the application using "mvn clean package"

Now, I want to be able to load the joda-time plugin. If I run "grails plugin-info joda-time", I receive the following:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Information about Grails plugin
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Name: joda-time | Latest release: 1.4
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Joda-Time Plugin
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Author: Rob Fletcher
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Author's e-mail: rob@freeside.co
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Find more info here: http://gpc.github.com/grails-joda-time/
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

Joda Time integration for Grails


Dependency Definition
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    :joda-time:1.4


Required Repositories
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     http://plugins.grails.org
     http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins/
     http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/
     http://svn.codehaus.org/grails/trunk/grails-plugins
     http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/
     http://repo.grails.org/grails/libs-releases/
     http://m2repo.spockframework.org/ext/
     http://m2repo.spockframework.org/snapshots/

Transitive Dependencies
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.1 (test)
     org.jodd:jodd-wot:3.3.1 (test)
```

I noticed that the above information is inconsistent with the website for the plugin (https://grails.org/plugin/joda-time). The website indicates that version 1.5 is the latest and includes an installation command that is incompatible with Grails > 2.3. It also shows an invalid github location, the correct location seems to be https://github.com/gpc/joda-time

I include this plugin into my BuildConfig.groovy file as follows:

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
...

    plugins {
        ...

        compile ":joda-time:1.4"

        ...
    }
}
```

I also include the dependency into the pom.xml as follows:

```
<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <type>zip</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

When I execute "mvn package", grails (through maven) picks up and downloads the plugin. However, any attempt to reference the plugin within a groovy class in order to access the FormattingTagLib class fails. I have also tried including all repositories within the joda-time information page as well as the transitive dependencies but cannot get grails to pick up the plugin.

Can someone please assist on how to get grails (though maven) to download this plugin and make the classes accessible so that I can reference them within a groovy class.

I cannot alter the version of Grails to solve this problem and I must build with maven.

Comment: Right click on pom.xml and then select second run option. Then run this command         "clean install" which will install the plugin in your maven repository. Check will this help you.

Comment: Thanks Santosh. I tried that. I have also tried cleaning out my entire cache and re-populating it. The only conclusion I can reach is that the Joda-Time plugin is not supported with the maven build. I have been forced to remove it as a dependency. I have a simple grails project with a maven pom file and test cases that show this.